# Cant reset password my wordpress password not even with phpMyAdmin

Tags: login

I cant login on my wordpress site. 
I can't reset my password since no mail address is configured.
When I try the phpMyAdmin method and click user it just says: MySQL returned an empty result.

Comment: I see you've tagged your question as wordpress.com, the premium hosting service, is this correct?  If you're a wordpress.com user you should contact wordpress.com support and the question will be closed as offtopic, this stack is for development with the open source WordPress, aka self hosted site installed via wordpress.org.

Comment: So you click `wp_users` (or `XYZ_users` if custom prefix) in PhpMyAdmin and it shows an empty result?

Comment: Yes I click on wpqm_users and it returns: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0008 seconds.). Thanks for the information the tag was changed.